# Slow Webcam Feed GTK

Tags: opencv, gtk, cairo

so I have a webcam through creating a pixbuf from a numpy image of an OpenCV capture, but said capture is sadly too slow, essentially my code looks like this.

```
builder.get_object('VideoCanvas').connect('draw', VideoCanvasDrawCb)

...

def VideoCanvasDrawCb(videoCanvas, context):
    success, frame = capture.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (480, 360))
    # Slowing down video recording
    for i in range(0, 3): output.writeFrame(frame)
    height, width, depth = frame.shape
    pixelBuffer = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data(frame.tostring(),
    GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, width, height, width * 3, None, None)
    builder.get_object('VideoCanvas').set_from_pixbuf(pixelBuffer)
```

The code runs fine until I get to the last function, set_from_pixbuf, whereas the GUI slows down a ton... I tried substituting the GtkImage by a GtkDrawingArea and painting the pixbuf with cairo. But the performance is the same...

Is there another way to render the pixbuf in realtime while not completely slowing down the whole application?